# Convert PHP procedural code into OOP method chaining...are maintainability and readability worth the trouble?

Tags: php, oop, refactoring

I had a medium-size task done in procedural style so I thought of converting the code to OOP for ease of maintenance. The original code was a big block in a single file and what I did was: 
 - Break down the task into functions which handle a part of the task 
 - Put the functions into a class for method chaining

After conversion, the code become like this:

```
$obj = new Class();
$result = $obj->task1()->task2()->task3()->task4()->getResult();
```

I can either leave it like this or further convert each task into a class for more abstraction. What are your takes on refactoring code just for maintainability and readability (and possibly portability once I break down the functions further and convert them into classes) ?

Comment: The closest you can get to pointers in php is to use `&$variableName`.

Comment: I don't see how chaining makes the code "better" (I'm not arguing against refactoring and modularization, mind). It looks like this chaining is just munging state inside "$obj" unless you're returning new objects (which may be good, but I doubt it is the case here).

Comment: @pst: it was not my intention to make it better, just to modularise things for later maintenance.

Comment: @fred: and that's not making it better?

Comment: Question is hard to answer because it's much too generic. Basically it asks: "is refactoring worth the trouble?" - which cannot be answered.

Comment: @markus: I noticed, so I edited my question. And yes, I think it would be better for the next person who takes over my code.

Comment: All you need to do is estimate time. See how long the code has to be maintained and how much time it takes to modify it compared to the time you spend to refactor it and time it saves. If the latter is less, you could refactor it.

Answer (score 2):

Classes are not bags of functions, and method chainning is not a valid reason for moving to OOP. Read about OOP principles and what it can do better than procedural.